# Using Cmake to output library informations

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

Hello I know I could use the GUI of cmake to just output information of library with simple commands:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
MESSAGE("${OpenCV_DIR}")
MESSAGE("${OpenCV_LIBS}")
```

I would like to use this commands from the dos command prompt. But I don t really know how to use the cmake tool from the command prompt. Maybe someone here know how to do things like this.

EDIT

ok the solutions you presented were right but as I see i didn t explain well what I wannted. I really wannted to get the results of the MESSAGE("${OpenCV_DIR}") without using the CMakeLists.txt file.

EDIT 2

Ok I have found what I have searched now ! I wannted to have pkg-config features with cmake on windows. Cmake gives this feature and here is illustrated how to do it:

http://blogs.kde.org/2011/11/09/cool-new-stuff-cmake-286-2-pkg-config-compatible-mode-added-use-eg-autotools

for my opencv search I tryed this and it worked:

```
cmake --find-package -DNAME=OpenCV -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=C -DMODE=COMPILE
```

don t know right now how to change gnu with visual studio but it is ok. 
thanks you all.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the first thing about the GUI... :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming CMake has been properly installed via the setup file that can be downloaded on the cmake.org website, the directory containing the `cmake.exe` executable should be present in your PATH.

Therefore, you can do the following (I'm assuming very little DOS knowledge):

1. Open a command prompt
2. Type `cd C:\the\directory\where\to\build` (replace by where your build directory is located, I will assume it is just below the directory where CMakeLists.txt is located)
3. Alter the current drive if necessary by typing `C:` or `D:` or whatever drive your project is located on.
4. Type `cmake ..` to invoke the cmake command line executable by specifying the relative path to the parent directory, which contains the CMakeLists.txt file, as argument.

You should see all expected output in the command prompt window.

CMake recommends to have out-of-source builds, meaning that, as you can see in the  CMake GUI, the source directory and the build directory should **not** be the same.
This has two benefits:

- you can have several build directories related to one source tree with different build configurations (debug, release, with static or dynamic linking... etc)
- the files generated by CMake don't risk to find themselves added to your Source Code Control system by accident.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to start cmake in the folder where this CMakeLists.txt is located, like this:

```
cmake .
```

Comment: Building directly in the source tree is strongly discouraged. You "dirty" the source tree, which can get quite confusing when mixing builds, source updates, source packaging and the like. It is generally a better idea to build in a separate directory, keeping the source tree "clean". (See SirDarius' answer.)

Comment: Since OP only seemed to want to get the output of those two variables, my assumption was that he didn't actually intend to build anything in the directory where he would have above CMakeFiles.txt, therefore the out-of-source build would be overkill since the directory would probably be deleted afterwards anyway. Shoould have mentioned that though.